# Bootstrap Navbar with search for WordPress with overlay Custmization

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Anyone please help to add html code inside php. Actually, I want to add search ovelay button synchronizing with menu. I have used theme separately, which is causing flickering.

php code of navigation navbar-nav

```
<?php
        wp_nav_menu([
            'menu'             =>   'primary',
            'theme_location'   =>   'primary',
            'container'        =>   'div',
            'container_id'     =>   'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker',
            'container_class'  =>   'collapse navbar-collapse bg-light',
            'menu_id'          =>   'main-menu',
            'menu_class'       =>   'navbar-nav ml-auto',
            'depth'            =>   2,
            'fallback_cb'      =>   'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'           =>   new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
        ]);
        ?>
```

Overlay Search

```
<div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="closeSearch()" title="Close Overlay"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></span>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e("Click Here to Search your Keywords","strap"); ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s">
      <button type="submit"> <i class="material-icons">search</i> </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="openBtn" onclick="openSearch()"><i class="material-icons">search</i></button>
```

I want both them to add. Please help.

Comment: Since you sound like a beginner I recommend you start [here](https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/edit-wordpress-theme-html/)